# Why am I getting a error on this if statement?

Tags: mysql

```
select if
(
(min(student_number)>1) or (max(student_number)<5500),'ok','Check Students'
)
from students;
```

Comment: can you show the mysql error you are getting

Comment: Its not that I am getting a error, I shouldnt have said that. The results are wrong. what I want is all student numbers should be between 1 and 5500. If anything else is present for student_number, then a student check is in order.

Comment: in this case you should replace `OR` by `AND`

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `OR` By `AND`:

```
select if
(
(min(student_number)>1) and (max(student_number)<5500),'ok','Check Students'
)
from students;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select if(min_sn > 1 or max_sn < 5500, 'ok', 'Check Students')
from (select 
        min(student_number) as min_sn,
        max(student_number) as max_sn
      from students) x
```

This will perform reasonably well too.

Note: It seems almost certain you should use `and` instead of `or` in your test. Think about it...

Answer (score 0):

There is a third alternative if you want to test that it is within a range.  Use between.

select if(student_number between 1 and 5500, 'Ok', 'Check Students') from students;

As long as there are any rows in your table - that will work.  If there are no rows, then you will get an empty set.